# Most recent dated directory

Tags: bash, date, unix

I have a directory which contains sub-directories in format of year/month/day.

```
2016/
2017/

2016/:
01/
02/
..
..

2016/01/:
01/
02/
...

...
2017/:
01/
02/
..
..

2017/01/:
01/
02/
...

...
```

I want to get the most recent one.. That is, this directory list wont have today's directories. I want to get the most recent one say 2017/07/19 or 2017/07/18.. whichever is the most recent one.

I am using something like `DATE=(date +%Y/%m/%d)` to get today's date. How to get the previous dates ?

How to get that in a bash script?

Comment: You could use `ls | sort -nr | head -n 1` to get the highest year (i.e. the most recent year), use the same command again in the particular subdirectory to get the highest month and a third time to get the most recent day. Does this satisfy your needs or did I get your question wrong?

Comment: Please use the answers to answer questions. Do not post the answer in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It may satisfy your needs.
Run it in Bash (let us suppose today is 2017/07/20 and today's directory does not exist.)

```
~$  (echo $(date "+%Y/%m/%d today"); find 201{6,7} -type d) | sort | grep today -B 1 | head -n 1
2017/07/19
```

Even `2017/07/20` directory exists, it works.

```
~$  (echo $(date "+%Y/%m/%d today"); find 201{6,7} -type d) | sort | grep today -B 1 | head -n 1
2017/07/20
```